# Java - Read Hierarchical data from flat structure in text file and build hashmap

Tags: java, performance, collections, hashmap

I have a text file in which hierarchical data is available in flat structure in the text file.

```
child parent
Y,     X
Z,     Y
A,     Z
```

Its like X is parent of Y , which itself parent of Z and Z is further parent of A It can appear in any order in the file.   I need to build a hashmap in which key should be element and value should be list of all the ancestor elements .
For example hashmap should have entries based on above data like this

A=[Z, Y, X], Y=[X], Z=[Y, X].

I have written a code in java to build this hashmap. Just need to know if there is more efficient way to do this .?
Logic is

1. Read the entire file in the hashmap  in which child is key and parent is the value
2. From the hashmap created above recursively traverse for each child and build the list of parents.

   ```
   public class Test {
   public static final String FILE_NAME = "dataset1";
   public static final HashMap<String,String> inputMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
   public static final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> parentChildMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

   private static void readTextFile(String aFileName) throws IOException {

     Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);

     try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] dataArray  = line.split(",");
             String child = dataArray[0];
             String parent = dataArray[1];

             inputMap.put(child, parent);
           }      
       }
     }
   public static ArrayList<String> getParents(String childId, ArrayList<String> parents) {

      if (childId == null)
       return parents;

     String parentId = inputMap.get(childId);
     if(parentId!=null) parents.add(parentId);
      getParents(parentId, parents);

      return parents;
   }

   public static void main(String[] s) throws IOException {
     readTextFile(FILE_NAME);
     for(String child : inputMap.keySet()) {
       ArrayList<String> parents = getParents(child, new ArrayList<String>());
       parentChildMap.put(child, parents);
   }
    }
   ```

Comment: Cana child have more than one parent?

Comment: No ,but parent can have their own parents  and Child need all of them

Answer (score 3):

The recursion is already pretty efficient. Here's what you can optimize:

- Put recursion into a loop
- Use memoization in recursion/loop (avoid recomputing)
- Do not recompute ancestors every time getParent is called, precompute results and store them

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "dataset1";
    public static final HashMap<String, String> inputMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> parentChildMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    private static void readTextFile(String aFileName) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] dataArray = line.split(",");
                String child = dataArray[0];
                String parent = dataArray[1];

                inputMap.put(child, parent);
            }
        }

        // this replaces the recursion:
        for (String k : inputMap.keySet()) {
            String ok = k;
            ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (true) {
                // if this has already been computed, use old answer
                if (parentChildMap.containsKey(k)) {
                    tmp.addAll(parentChildMap.get(k));
                    break;
                }
                if (inputMap.containsKey(k)) {
                    String v = inputMap.get(k);
                    tmp.add(v);
                    k = v;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            parentChildMap.put(ok, tmp);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getParents(String childId) {
        // do not recompute
        return parentChildMap.get(childId);
    }
}
```

Comment: He said that he needs a `list`: "I need to build a hashmap in which key should be element and value should be **list** of all the ancestor elements"

Comment: Same thing - or really easily converted - http://beginnersbook.com/2014/08/convert-hashset-to-a-list-arraylist/

Comment: Thanks AJC . Do you mean to say , I can achieve the desired behavior with this single map only while reading from text file ? I doubt it because a child's parent can have more parents. How will this logic give me all the ancestors .?

Comment: @Ravi This is basically an adjacency list - it does work for what you need

Comment: Do you mean to say, after making your changes,  recursive logic will still stay as it is ? Then I agree it will work . I wanted to find out an efficient in which i can avoid recursive logic somehow to build the final hashmap .

Comment: @Ravi sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: {A=[Z], Y=[X], Z=[Y]} this is the map, I will get in case I avoid recursion . Thats not what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95640/discussion-between-ravi-and-ajc).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for "more efficient way", so here is my critique (minor) and my suggestion.

- Don't initialize `line` to `null`. Just declare it.
- Don't use `split()`. It may split to more than two values, and it has to create an array. Just use `indexOf()`.

So, first method becomes (compacted some):

```
public static final Map<String, String> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
private static void readTextFile(String aFileName) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(aFileName),
                                                         StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            int idx = line.indexOf(',');
            inputMap.put(/*child*/line.substring(0, idx),
                         /*parent*/line.substring(idx + 1));
        }      
    }
}
```

Now for the suggestion.

Your code resolves the same parents multiple times, e.g. when retrieving parents of `A`, it has to walk the entire parent chain `Z`, `Y`, `X`, and when retrieving parents of `Z`, it has to walk the parent chain `Y`, `X`. You're doing the same walk multiple times.

It would be more efficient to do it only once. Since data is unordered, you have to do it using recursion. I've renamed the `parentChildMap` to a more appropriate `ancestorMap`.

```
public static final Map<String, List<String>> ancestorMap = new HashMap<>();
private static List<String> getAncestors(String child) {
    // Check if ancestors already resolved
    List<String> ancestors = ancestorMap.get(child);
    if (ancestors == null) {
        // Find parent
        String parent = inputMap.get(child);
        if (parent == null) {
            // Child has no parent, i.e. no ancestors
            ancestors = Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            // Find ancestors of parent using recursive call
            List<String> parentAncestors = getAncestors(parent);
            if (parentAncestors.isEmpty()) {
                // Parent has no ancestors, i.e. child has single ancestor (the parent)
                ancestors = Collections.singletonList(parent);
            } else {
                // Child's ancestors is parent + parentAncestors
                ancestors = new ArrayList<>(parentAncestors.size() + 1);
                ancestors.add(parent);
                ancestors.addAll(parentAncestors);
            }
        }
        // Save resolved ancestors
        ancestorMap.put(child, ancestors);
    }
    return ancestors;
}
```

If you don't care about the optimization of using `emptyList()` and `singletonList()`, or having comments, it can be compacted to:

```
private static List<String> getAncestors(String child) {
    List<String> ancestors = ancestorMap.get(child);
    if (ancestors == null) {
        ancestorMap.put(child, ancestors = new ArrayList<>());
        String parent = inputMap.get(child);
        if (parent != null) {
            ancestors.add(parent);
            ancestors.addAll(getAncestors(parent));
        }
    }
    return ancestors;
}
```

The `main` method then becomes:

```
public static final String FILE_NAME = "dataset1";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    readTextFile(FILE_NAME);
    for (String child : inputMap.keySet())
        getAncestors(child); // Ignore return value
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. This is definately cleaner and efficient way . Just one issue , I noticed .  Even though the X is not child of anyone , still this logic builds the map with X as the key and value as empty list. But neverthless , this is much more elegant than the original code